# I Have Yealink Cp960 Network Echo Cancelation conference speaker

Tags: networking, laptop, audio

I Have Yealink Cp960 Network Echo Cancelation conference speaker and i use in google meet and zoom video conference in laptop with usb cable. my laptop and speaker in both same network it is possible to use that speaker over network through laptop for conference.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Have you already tried connecting the conference phone to your laptop? Specs say it has USB ports on it. What happens when you connect it to your laptop? Are you trying to attend the meeting using your Laptop but use the conference phone connected to your laptop over the network instead? Please EDIT your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Conference speaker connect with usb is ok. but i want use this network spekaer play from over laptop my laptop and network speaker both are in same network

Answer (score 0):

According to the [datasheet](http://www.yealink.com/upfiles/Newsletter/2017/YealinkCP960Datasheet.pdf) for that Conference speaker, you can connect it over Bluetooth.